# Drupal 6 - how to set up a VIEWS block?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I can't figure out how to set up a block view for this in Drupal 6:

Users submit a picture.  If it is approved, I upload it to the site.

There is a node that shows the details of the picture and the author information.  I want to have a block that says, MORE BY THIS AUTHOR.  This block would list more images that this author has submitted. How can I do this?

The URL is:  mysite/content/name-of-image  so I don't know how to create a view that shows all the images by this author since the user name is not in the URL.  Can someone tell me how to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add a user:uid argument to the view.
- choose "provide deafult argument" option for this argument.
- choose "php code" as default argument type.
- enter following php code:

  ```
  if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {  
      $node = node_load(arg(1));  
      $uid = $node->uid;  
  }  
  return $uid;
  ```

in your case you want the uid from a cck field of the node, so the php code should be this:

```
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {  
    $node = node_load(arg(1));
    //if the field contains a user id
    $uid = $node->field_authorid[0][value];

    //if the field contains a username
    $user = user_load(array('name' => check_plain($node->field_authorname[0][value]))); 
    $uid = $user->uid; 
}  
return $uid;
```

Now you'll have the author user id from the node in url.
Now you can add fields to the view from nodes created by this author.

NOTE: the view preview won't show any results, so you'll have to save this view and test it outside the views builder.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think you understand what I am attempting.  Why would the argument be the node:id?  I have access to the content_author field in this "Image Details" node.  I just need to somehow display all the images ONLY THIS author has submitted.

Comment: sorry, i misead. I thought that the "more about this author" should be in the block view and the overview of more images in a seperate view. I'll change the answer

Comment: It's not "more comments by this author" it's "More Images by this User".  Also, I mentioned that **I** approve and upload the authors image, so the node:id is ALWAYS me - not the author of the image.  So, I have a page with a big picture that a user has submitted, and it tells all the details next to it including the author's username.  Below that is a block view that should show all the other images that this author has submitted.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer and writing the code.  However, the uid is always me, not the content author.  Also, I mentioned that in the url, there is no username or userid, it's the name of the image (so arg(1) is never numeric).

Comment: arg() should match the drupal url arguments (without rewrite rules) like example.com/?q=node/555 where arg(0) == 'node' and arg(1) == 555.
this code workds for me. I'll double check it

Comment: My url is mysite/content/image-title so arg(0) is content and arg(1) is image-title.

Comment: your images are nodes, right ?
so mysite/content/image-title is the clean url for
mysie/?q=node/555, 555 being the image-title's node id.
by the way the view's preview won't show any results, but should work.

Comment: Haven't thought of that, first image being repeated in the block. If i come up with a solution for this, i will post it here.
glad i could help.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work.  It's because the uid is always me, not the author of the image.  So, the block is actually showing ALL the images (not the ones by the image author) since I am the user id of every image.

Comment: if you are the author of every image, isn't it logical that the uid is always you ?

Comment: No, some user, let's say "Jack" uploads an image.  I approve it.  Then I post it using CCK fields with details on the image including the user's name ("Jack"), the description of the image, the date, etc.  Then, below this image, there is a block that says, "More by this user".  This should list all the other images that "Jack" has submitted.  With your code, it filters all the images that *I* am the author of - which is all of them, not the ones by "Jack".

Comment: No problem. If the node has a cck field that contains Jack's uid, we can still select that. In the php snippet in the answer change $uid = $node->uid to $uid = field_cckfieldname[0][value] where cckfieldname is the ... cck fieldname of the field containing jack's user id. If the field doesn't contain a user id, but a username, add this line: $uid = user_load(array('name' => check_plain($uid)));
$uid = $uid->uid;

updated the answer

Comment: Works!  Thanks for sticking through this and helping me.